# ImportError: No module named *****

Tags: python, import, module

I am beginner in python

i have following directory structure

```
python_programs/
                addition.py
                info/_init_.py
                     msg1.py
                     msg2.py
                     msg3.py
```

In addition.py i have the following code:-

```
import Info  
Info.msg1()  
Info.msg2()  
Info.msg3()
```

In *init*.py i have the following code

```
from msg1 import msg1
from msg2 import msg2
from msg3 import msg3
```

In msg1.py i have the following code:-

```
def msg1():  
    print "This is msg1"
```

In msg2.py i have the following code:-

```
def msg2():  
    print "This is msg2"
```

In msg3.py i have the following code:-

```
def msg3():  
    print "This is msg3"
```

but when i tried to run the addition.py file

it is giving me error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "addition.py", line 2, in <module>
    import Info  
ImportError: No module named Info
```

Comment: `__init__.py` requires **two** underscores before and after `init`. You have only one on either side.

Comment: Python module names are case sensitive as well; your package is called `info`, all lower case, but your code imports `Info`, with a capital `I`.

Comment: i added the other underscores also but result is same

Comment: did u tried changing Info to info in your import

Comment: thanks Martijn Pieters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made two mistakes:

- To create a package, the file must be named `__init__.py` (double underscores on either side), not `_init_.py`.
- Python is case sensitive. You named your package `info` (lowercase), but try to import `Info` (uppercase `I`); these don't match. Rename one or the other to match case correctly.